findById(Long id) doesn´t work? on spring
I have the following Sprig entity, with its repository, service, DTO, and controller. When I am in the incisoController and I call the function incisoSerice.findById(id) it works correctly, just like when I am in articuloController and call articuloSerice.findById(id). The problem arises when I call articuloSerice.findById(id) passing as a parameter an id of an existing article from incisoController; in that case, it doesn't bring me anything. The Inciso class is as follows:
@Entity
@Table(name = "incisos")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false) 
public class Inciso extends Ley {

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_inciso_padre")
        @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "numero", "denominacion", "detalle", "estado",
                        "fechaAlta", "fechaBaja", "fechaModificacion", "motivoModificacion", "activo",
                        "novedadesPersonales",
                        "tipoLey", "articuloPadre", "incisoPadre", "incisos", "subIncisos", "subArticulos" })
        private Inciso incisoPadre;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "incisoPadre", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "numero", "denominacion", "detalle", "estado",
                        "fechaAlta", "fechaBaja", "fechaModificacion", "motivoModificacion", "activo",
                        "novedadesPersonales",
                        "tipoLey", "articuloPadre", "incisoPadre", "incisos", "subIncisos", "subArticulos" })
        private List<Inciso> subIncisos = new ArrayList<>();
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_articulo")
        @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "numero", "denominacion", "detalle", "estado",
                        "fechaAlta", "fechaBaja", "fechaModificacion", "motivoModificacion", "activo",
                        "novedadesPersonales",
                        "tipoLey", "articuloPadre", "incisoPadre", "incisos", "subIncisos", "subArticulos" })
        private Articulo articulo;
}

The corresponding controller for Inciso is as follows (omitting unnecessary code):
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/inciso")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class IncisoController {
    @Autowired
    IncisoService incisoService;
    @Autowired
    ArticuloService articuloService;
    @Autowired
    LeyController leyController;
    @Autowired
    NovedadPersonalService novedadPersonalService;

    @GetMapping("/detail/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Inciso>> getById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        if (!incisoService.activo(id))
            return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("Inciso no encontrado"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        Inciso inciso = incisoService.findById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity(inciso, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

private Inciso createUpdate(Inciso inciso, IncisoDto incisoDto) {

        Ley ley = leyController.createUpdate(inciso, incisoDto);
        inciso = (Inciso) ley;

        if (inciso.getArticulo() != null && (inciso.getArticulo().getId() != incisoDto.getIdArticulo())
                && incisoDto.getIdArticulo() != null) {
            inciso.setArticulo(articuloService.findById(incisoDto.getIdArticulo()).get());
        }
    }
 @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody IncisoDto incisoDto) {
        ResponseEntity<?> respuestaValidaciones = leyController.validationsCreate(incisoDto);

        if (respuestaValidaciones.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            Inciso inciso = createUpdate(new Inciso(), incisoDto);
            incisoService.save(inciso);
            return new ResponseEntity<Mensaje>(new Mensaje("Inciso creado correctamente"), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return respuestaValidaciones;
        }
    }

Additionally, Inciso has a 1:N relationship with itself. If I call incisoService.findById(idIncisoPadre) from the Inciso controller with an existing id in the database, it also doesn't fetch the element, even though idIncisoPadre should indeed retrieve an element from the Inciso class
I try to get the correct value of incisoPadre with incisoService.findById(idIncisoPadre) in the incisoController

put your Lay class
